# Twig/variable support in Custom block HTML

Tags: theming, 8, blocks, tokens

I'm trying to understand if/how you insert Twig variables in blocks in the custom block library.

To clarify, the block's HTML has been configured via the UI at `/admin/structure/block/block-content`

Standard Twig syntax, e.g. a 'say-something' tag like `{{ base_path ~ directory }}` - which I want so I can set an `<img src` attibute correctly - doesn't seem to be parsed at all and I don't see a way to use Tokens.

Examining the HTML source with Twig debugging on, it's theme hook is listed as "field", so if I add a preprocess function:

```
function themename_preprocess_field(array &$variables, $hook) {
  xdebug_break():
}
```

- that's being called rather too often
- when it does reach the custom block, there doesn't seem to be anything in $variables that labels it as such, other than a render array with the processed text:

`$variables['items'][0]['content]['#text']`

What's the simplest approach for this? Is the only way to do it to write a module?

Thanks,
William

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use twig variables in the body field of a block (or a node). But you can use tokens. Install the modules [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) and [Token Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter). You need to add the token filter to the text format you are using in the body field.

Comment: Thanks. For benefit of others: you edit the text format via `/admin/config/content/formats`, choose Configure, check 'Replaces global and entity tokens with their values'. There's a list of all available tokens at `/admin/help/token`